# Is GPP Item Level Targeting any faster or slower than WMI filtering?

Tags: group-policy

I need to filter a GPO so that it only applies if an application is installed. From what I can see, I should be able to do this either with WMI or with GPP item level targeting. Is there a performance difference between the two? If it makes a difference, there are three items in GPP that will have targeting applied (I'm assuming this means three queries vs one when using WMI filtering).

Comment: in this case wmi will be slower since it has to actually query installed products.

Comment: I was thinking I might be able to use WMI to look for a registry key or the existence of a file. Am I incorrect?

Comment: You can use wmi to both look for a key and file but more then likely gpp will do it faster.

Comment: I can't find any documentation to support one or the other, but I suspect both are fast enough that it doesn't really matter. I personally find item-level targeting much easier and more intuitive to configure.

Comment: Also, not all WMI queries are create equal. For example, `SELECT * FROM Win32_Product` is really, really slow. What exactly are you trying to detect?

Comment: I was thinking that Item Level Targeting would have to execute multiple filters as opposed to just one WMI filter. I'm trying to ensure that the Citrix Receiver client is installed before deploying icons to a machine. I ended up going with Item Level Targetting, which seems to be pretty quick at this point.